# Log scale with stat_binhex

Tags: r, ggplot2, logarithm

I have these two distributions I want to plot with log scale for both axes:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(99)
data <- data.frame(vec1 = as.integer(rlnorm(10000, sdlog = 2)),
                   vec2 = as.integer(rlnorm(10000, sdlog = 2)))
```

I can easily obtain the result with the `geom_point()`

```
ggplot(data, aes(vec1, vec2)) + geom_point() + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
```

but not with `stat_binhex()`

```
ggplot(data, aes(vec1, vec2)) + stat_binhex() + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
```

which will generate an error

```
Error in if (!missing(xbnds) && any(sign(xbnds - range(x)) == c(1, -1))) stop("'xbnds' must encompass range(x)") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Is is possible?

Comment: You have 0 values in your data and that makes problem. If you add some constant to `vec1` and `vec2`, you will see that scales work

Answer (score 0):

Following [Didzis Elferts'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1857266/didzis-elferts) directions to get the question closed (@[Didzis Elferts'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1857266/didzis-elferts), please feel free to recycle my answer if you like). Code below.

[image]

```
 … 
    ggplot(data, aes(vec1+1, vec2+1)) + stat_binhex() + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
```

Alternatively you can remove the `0` values

```
bar <- subset(data, vec1 != 0 & vec2 != 0)
ggplot(bar, aes(vec1, vec2)) + stat_binhex() + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
```